# How to stop node.js functions/loop via request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running on a fastify server and when I send a request, I get a ton of data from mongodb and start a for loop to process each item. This can take ~ 30 minutes. Each item is "processed" by sending to ffmpeg, redis pub->sub, and then a socket to the client.

```
 // Streams controller
exports.renderStreams = async function (req, reply) {
    const streams = await Stream.find({}).sort({ createdAt: -1 })//.limit(5)
    const renderedStreams = renderStreams(this, streams);
    return { success: true, streams: streams.length };
}

// renderStreams
const renderStreams = (fastify, streams = []) => {
    const { redis } = fastify;
    const channel = "streams";
    for (let i = 0; i < streams.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(async () => {
            const stream = streams[i];
            await renderStream(redis, channel, stream);
        }, i * 200)
    }
}
```

I am wondering in this for loop, how can I either "pause" it or stop it completely (or both?) via another request, maybe when I call `/api/streams/stop`.

How would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use socket.io to do communications with your script while it is still running, so you would create a function to stop the loop and when you get the notification from socket.io you would run it. Documentation link: https://socket.io/docs/v4/

Comment: Alright that part works, however what would the code look to "stop" or "pause" it? I mean, I get the socket part.

Comment: @kinx Whats is ur loop now?